# Need help in running Rest API in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I'm Trying to RestAPI in Jenkins Job but it is not working. Below is the script which i'm running. this script will fetch the SessionID of an application and store it in a variable. this script is running fine in git bash but not working in Jenkins. So can anyone help me on this.

var=$(curl --silent 'url/Login?sUserId=userId&sPassword=Password | sed -nr s/.*>(.*)<.*/\1/p')
echo $var

Thanks In Advance,

Phanindra

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me you are trying to do a sed inside a single quote string. I doubt it would produce what you are expecting. sed won't be executed

What I do to debug a command line is to go step by step.

is var having the value expected with var=$(echo 'test').

is var having the value expected when I only call curl without the sed command

Comment: Hi Fredericrous... Yeah i'm trying to sed the result of the curl command. can you pls let me know how to sed the results?